# PyMysql Update query within function using global cursor

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to run an update query within a function using a global cursor that has been set in a 
"with MySQLdb.connect" statement in the main body. For some reason the update queries in the main body work though and the queries in the functions dont work :(
Is there a way to get the error because none is being generated,

```
import MySQLdb
import sys
def updateFunction(data):
    global cur
    cur.execute("UPDATE1")
    sys.exit(0)
if __name__=="__main__":
    data="sample data, not important"
    with MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="user",passwd="pass",db="db") as cur:
        cur.execute("UPDATE2")
        updateFunction(data)
```

in that example UPDATE2 would run and UPDATE1 wouldnt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that updating queries needed to be commited, and that needed to be done through `connection.commit()`.

Comment: This is only required when something like [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) is used to automatically disable `autocommit` on new connections.

Comment: @jordanm I didnt know that, i have only used mysql with php up to now and i havent had to commit updates and inserts, thank you.